# how to make 1:many relationship between models with different query ( linq syntax )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-fluent-api

i have this :

**Models:**

```
{
   [Table("Requests")]
    public partial class RequestsModel
    {
        public RequestsModel()
        {
            this.CountView = new HashSet<RequestCountViewModels>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Sender { get; set; }
        public int? Type { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int? Adtype { get; set; }
        public int? Status { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? SDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? EDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PayDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RespDate { get; set; }
        public long? Counter { get; set; }
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        public string Maps { get; set; }
        public int? AccBy { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RequestCountViewModels> CountView { get; set; }
    }
  [Table("Counter")]
    public partial class RequestCountViewModels
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ParentMdl")]
        public int? ReqId { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }

        public virtual RequestsModel ParentMdl { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Time { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**HomeController:**

```
public virtual ActionResult Advs(string id)
    {
        var model = _requestService.GetAdvertise(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        return View(model);

    }
```

**RequestsService.cs**

```
  public RequestsModel GetAdvertise(int AdID)
        {
            return
                _ctx.Requests
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == AdID && a.Type == 1);
        }
```

**RequestsConfig.cs**

```
  HasMany(a => a.CountView)
                .WithRequired(a => a.ParentMdl)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.ReqId);
```

these r my code, now i wanna make relationship between **RequestsModel** and **RequestCountViewModel** so that retrieve related table data from remove db
it will get request table, but need to retrieve viewcount table for every row and fill into ICOLLECTION
help me! sorry for weak english

Comment: sorry, **from remote db**

Comment: `return  _ctx.Requests.Include(p => p.CountView).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == AdID && a.Type == 1);`

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak when i write .Include(p => p.CountView), have syntax error  with  red underline !! says : **Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type** !! i don't know what to do !

Comment: do you have a reference to `using System.Data.Entity`?

Comment: i'd no considered that, but i've did it!

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak it's fixed, but still now retrieving CountView Table. where i cant add this :     ' _ctx.Counters
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToList(); ' to read countview table

Comment: **still not** retrieving ...

Comment: put `.CountView.ToList()` at the end

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak not worked yet, when i use **CountViews.Count()** in my View Page, it returns 14 ( it's right ) but when i use `foreach ( var item in Model.CountView) Html.DisplayFor(a=> item.Time)`, it returns nothing !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to make something like this:

```
public GetData()
{
    var data = _ctx.Requests
        .Include(p => p.CountView)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(a => a.CountView)
        .ToList();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Not worked yet. I think there is an problem for making relationship between 2 tables. But i dont know what is, and debugger warm me not !! It can't make foreignkey for RequestViewCountModel. Help me ! 

Comment: but the above function returns something?

Comment: it returns RequestModel , but not ViewCountModel ! returns 22 times ( ViewCount.Count ) , but Collection is empty ... i think foreignkey not created or something like this,

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of my own problem
**RequestCountViewModels** should be like this :

```
[Table("Counter")]
    public partial class RequestCountViewModels
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ReqId")]
        public virtual RequestsModel ParentMdl { get; set; }
        public int ReqId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }
```

**RequestService.cs** :

```
  public virtual RequestsModel GetAdvertises(int AdID)
        {
            return _requests
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(v => v.ViewCounts)
                .Cacheable()
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == AdID && a.Type == 1);
        }
```

and in view, `for loop` statement should be used instead of `foreach`